# merge from commit to commit

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a commits in my branch MASTER

```
1.commit 4930da17d8dd23d650ed38435d8b421816a0c451
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 14:34:18 2015 +0530

2.commit e1ebbbb599ee20ebec3ca92c26266d9fd16e7ccc
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 13:22:20 2015 +0530

3.commit e1721686be4be1eaf1618e199c70477c1383068f
  Merge: b1fdca0 51c7c21
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:11:50 2015 +0530

4.commit b4ab3c164a3a8d93e0a71a94b5c561cb5e20ebf6
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:09:56 2015 +0530

5.commit 167b1d10258381f09663ce61fa88ce3bbcd404c4
  Merge: 88f01ad 5ed302b
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:09:21 2015 +0530

6.commit c61bcadac673e1c83f4c14b66d56e23b12fa3198
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:07:58 2015 +0530
```

I have another branch called TEST_MASTER

Now I want to merge from 3rd commit to 6th commit, from the branch MASTER to TEST_MASTER. Means

```
3.commit e1721686be4be1eaf1618e199c70477c1383068f
  Merge: b1fdca0 51c7c21
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:11:50 2015 +0530

4.commit b4ab3c164a3a8d93e0a71a94b5c561cb5e20ebf6
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:09:56 2015 +0530

5.commit 167b1d10258381f09663ce61fa88ce3bbcd404c4
  Merge: 88f01ad 5ed302b
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:09:21 2015 +0530

6.commit c61bcadac673e1c83f4c14b66d56e23b12fa3198
  Date:   Sat Dec 5 12:07:58 2015 +0530
```

Cherry-pick I tried, It is working.

In my case I have nearly 100 commits, Is there any other way to do merge like

```
from <commit-id> to to <commit-id>
```

Comment: What does `from 3rd commit to 6th commit` mean?  Can you show us a diagram of what you want to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch)

Answer (score 2):

As I explained in "[How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309)", you can use git cherry-pick to merge a range of commits, not just commit by commit.

> If you want to pick the range B through D (inclusive) that would be `git cherry-pick B^..D`

That does allow you to merge "from `<commit-id>` to `<commit-id>`"

---

The OP reports that a range revert fails with:

```
Commit xxx is a merge but no -m option was given. fatal: cherry-pick failed.
```

And when trying to chose a non-merge commit:

```
git cherry-pick -m 1 <non-merge-commit>^..<sha1> 
  error: Mainline was specified but commit <xxx> is not a merge.  
  fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

That last message won't be there with Git 2.21 (Q1 2019):

See [commit 1c32013](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c320135e12c41d0f1ced7bd119c7ae0b65f307e), [commit 4d67b4e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d67b4e4740895ddc5b8bd4f205e159999c1b974), [commit 37897bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37897bfc27d3003dddf7722113e676e925fe9e21), [commit c812bd4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c812bd4669d8907186dab8aed47f2c83dfb93fff) (14 Dec 2018) by [Sergey Organov (`sorganov`)](https://github.com/sorganov).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 77fbd96](https://github.com/git/git/commit/77fbd96aebf794bc9131bd175be500eac2edcd2d), 18 Jan 2019)</sup>

> "`git cherry-pick -m1`" was forbidden when picking a non-merge commit, even though there *is* parent number 1 for such a commit.
>
> This was done to avoid mistakes back when "`cherry-pick`" was about picking a single commit, but is no longer useful with "`cherry-pick`" that can pick a range of commits.
>
> **Now the "`-m$num`" option is allowed when picking *any* commit**, as long as `$num` names an existing parent of the commit.
>
> Technically this is a backward incompatible change; hopefully nobody is relying on the error-checking behaviour.

---

You can see the discussion leading to allowing '`cherry-pick -m 1`' for non-merge commits in [this thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqsh5gt9sm.fsf@gitster-ct.c.googlers.com/):

From Junio C. Hamano, main maintainer of Git:

> > When cherry-picking multiple commits, it's impossible to have both merge- and non-merge commits on the same command-line.
> >     Not specifying '`-m 1`' results in cherry-pick refusing to handle merge commits, while specifying '`-m 1`' fails on non-merge commits.
>
> Allowing "`-m1`" even when picking a single parent commit, because the 1-st parent is defined for such a commit, makes sense, especially when running a cherry-pick on a range, exactly for the above reason.
>   It is slightly less so when cherry-picking a single commit, but not by a large margin.
>
> I think the original reasoning for requiring "`-m $n`" not present, especially because cherry-pick was originally for replaying only a single commit, was because it would lead somebody to propose that the command should behave as if `-m1` is always given (and when trying to cherry-pick a merge relative to its second parent, give `-m2` to override it), which in turn encourage the 'first-parent is special' world-view from the tool-side.
>
> IOW, "The worldview to treat the first-parent chain specially is correct, because Git has many features to work with that worldview conveniently" was something we wanted to avoid.
>   Rather: "Such and such workflows benefit from
>   treating the first-parent chain specially, so let's add features to do so" was we wanted to do.
>   And of course, back then cherry-pick that allows mixture of merges and single-parent commits to be picked, which would have made the need to do something like this patch does felt greater, did not exist.
>
> Now, it appears, at least to me, that the world pretty much accepted that the first-parent worldview is often very convenient and worth supporting by the tool, so the next logical step might be to set `opts->mainline` to 1 by default (and allow an explicit "`-m $n`" from the command line to override it).
>   But that should happen after this patch lands---it is logically a separate step, I would think.

And:

> The feature to give a range to cherry-pick came much much later in [7e2bfd3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e2bfd3f99f8d6e89c7b855675919dd5404e47a2) ("`revert`: allow cherry-picking more than one commit", 2010-06-02) that first appeared in v1.7.2-rc0.

(as [I reported here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309))

> The feature to allow picking a merge commit came in [7791ecbc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7791ecbc62b792b3eaa6d722b6dadcea4d0f322d) ("`revert`/`cherry-pick`: work on merge commits as well", 2007-10-23), first appeared in v1.5.4-rc0.
>
> In the original context to pick a single commit, it made perfect sense to avoid mistakes by blindly passing '`-m 1`' to non-merge commit.
>   It may be fair to say that we failed to reconsider what to do with '`-m 1`' when we did [7e2bfd3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e2bfd3f99f8d6e89c7b855675919dd5404e47a2), but it is utterly an unfair history revisionism to say that it made little sense to disable it in the first place.
>
> The change to the code itself looks sane, but applying this patch alone will break existing tests whose expectations must be updated, and this new behaviour must be protected by a new test (or two) so that we won't accidentally stop accepting "`-m 1`" for a single-parent commit.

Comment: @ksvijay413 Be sure to replace B by the SHA1 of the oldest commit you want to merge, and D by the SHA1 of the newest commit.

Comment: D:\GitHub\hexgen\src>git cherry-pick 17eb265a5be195382ddb92dfdba3f4c264345a83^..b1fdca06aa187f3f525e993cc0681251b2df09ae
[range_2.0.primary bbcf9cd] For grids made a export button and put pdf,csv etc under it - just to avoid the clutter
 Author: Mallick <mallick@gmail.com>
 1 file changed, 8 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
error: Commit 699aa7121ff4f6bdd1480d004ab68fb95f6e7ba3 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed

Comment: @ksvijay413 it is best if your commits don't include merge commits. If they do include a merge commit, try at least to add `-m 1` to your cherry-pick command.

Comment: D:\GitHub\hexgen\src>git cherry-pick -m 1 17eb265a5be195382ddb92dfdba3f4c264345a83^..b1fdca06aa187f3f525e993cc0681251b2df09ae
error: Mainline was specified but commit 8d0e9d27f5fd3cb9934349b00efa060ddbd63bf1 is not a merge.
fatal: cherry-pick failed

Comment: @vijay three years latter, your cherry-pick (the one which returned "is not a merge. fatal: cherry-pick failed") will actually work lwith Git 2.21 (Q1 2019). See my edited answer above.

Comment: This new 2.21 behavior (allowing `-m1` for non-merge commits) is probably a good thing. Time will tell! :-)

Comment: @torek I have edited the answer to add the discussion (from the Git mailing-list) leading to that new feature: that will give you (and other readers) some context.