# How to merge specific commits from dev to master

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to merger some specific (not all) from dev to master. And Used below command which throws exception.

```
C:\Users\arrchana\New_Code\Paymentev\AmazonPaymente2etestserv\A2paymente2etestservService> git cherry-pick 5dc6112
error: Commit 5dc6112 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

How to resolve this issue?  Is there any other way to get the specific commit from dev and merge it with Master branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git cherry-pick says "...38c74d is a merge but no -m option was given"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229301/git-cherry-pick-says-38c74d-is-a-merge-but-no-m-option-was-given)

Comment: You cannot cherry pick a merge, because cherry picking applies the changes a commit made compared to its parent and a merge has two parents (which one should git pick?). Cherry pick one of the merge parents instead. See the question I linked above for more info

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this without using cherry-pick command?

Comment: @CaiusJard Note: that might change with Git 2.21: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34782687/6309

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to cherry pick a merge commit. While that can be done, it is most likely not what you want.

If you're trying to apply the changes from **a specific range of commits**, you will need to find the commit-ish (tags or sha1-hashes) for all of those commits by looking at the log.

You can then run `git cherry-pick hash1 hash2 hash3...`. Make sure those hashes are in the order in which they were committed!

---

If your specific change is *within* a merge commit, it gets harder.

First: **Don't make any changes other than resolving conflicts in a merge commit!**

With that out of the way: You can `git diff 5dc6112` the merge commit or `git show 5dc6112` to see if that contains your relevant changes. If it does, go:

```
git [diff/show] 5dc6112 | patch -p1
```

this will apply the diff to your current working directory. You can then commit those changes.